# VSTest runners broken

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, mstest, vstest

We're trying to implement unit tests in C# for VSTest in Visual Studio 2013 (or whatever driver VS2013 uses by default). The ordered test runner XML has absolute file paths in all the storage attributes. This means we're bound to the file structure of whichever developer wrote the tests. Is there any way we can make these relative paths? How are we supposed to automate these tests on the build server?